# How do I implement input.txt > output.txt in C

Tags: c, io, stream

How do I implement a single I/O stream in C? 
i.e. a > b
The code below does not transfer the text from input.txt to output.txt like I want it to.

```
#include <fcntl.h>   
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>   
#include <unistd.h>   

int main(void)
{
        int fd = open("/home/ubuntu/workspace/file2.txt", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT);
        if (fd < 0)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open file2.txt for writing\n");
            return(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        dup2(fd, 1);
        close(fd);
        execlp("a.out", "a.out", "file1.txt", NULL);
}
```

Comment: What does the code for `a.out` do? What is the current behaviour of your program? I suggest you check whether the `excelp` actually succeeded or not. Normally the current directory (`.`) is not in the PATH. So attempting to exec `a.out` would fail in that case.

Comment: Try using `cat` instead of `a.out`.

Comment: Why do you need to do this with `execlp()`? You can just write a simple loop in C that reads from `file1.txt` and writes to `file2.txt`.

Comment: Information I found online told me to: exec(executable here, executable here, input file here)

Comment: Can someone provide an example?

Comment: No. Stackoverflow specifically discourages asking for examples. That's what your search engine is for. Also, how about you read the [exec man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/execlp) which has all the details?

Comment: @jinan You didn't answer any of the other questions, such as the ones kaylam asked: What does `a.out` do? (Is `a.out` this program or a different one?) What does the program currently do? Why do you need to use exec to copy a file?

Answer (score 2):

If you're not forced to use `exec` you can use easy code that will write file1.txt to the designated output file:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define BUFFSIZE 10240

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int n, t, i;
    char buf[BUFFSIZE];
    t = open("file1.txt", O_RDONLY);

    while ((n = read(t, buf, BUFFSIZE)) > 0) {
        if (write(STDOUT_FILENO, buf, n) != n) {
            perror("Write Error");
        }
    }
    if (n < 0) {
        perror("Read Error");
    }
    if (close(t) == -1) {
        perror("Closing Error");
    }

    exit(0);
}
```

Test

```
./a.out a > c

dac@dac-Latitude-E7450 ~/C/twodec> more c
foo bar
bletch 
blahonga
```

Comment: I dont think this is doing some like: file1.txt > file2.txt but rather (some text) > someFile.txt. I am trying to send data from one file to the next.

Comment: I have solved similar problems. You may have a look at my Open Source C if you like https://github.com/montao/openshell I also have a very basic pipeline example: https://github.com/montao/pipeline You can take that code and use any way you like. Our hero Jonathan Leffler helped us write it.